# Driver's liability for friend passenger's losses in an accident

Tags: driving, new-zealand, negligence

Alice and Bob are friends. One day they decide to go on a road trip in Bob's car.

It has started freezing and the road may be icy. Bob drives below the speed limit and applies some extra care that he thinks is adequate, but his experience in driving on icy roads is by no means broad/extensive. In particular, he does not know that bridges freeze first, and signs saying that are missing — they are just not common there.

The car enters a bridge, loses control and rolls over. Because the two wear seat belts, the car is rigid and they are very lucky they manage to escape the car — shaken but with only minor or no injures. However, Alice's jacket is damaged. Also she is concerned that she might have been injured, so she visits a doctor for checkup. The doctor finds nothing requiring medical care.

The police investigates the incident and issues [Written Traffic Warning](http://www.police.govt.nz/news/commissioners-blog/traffic-warnings-trial) to Bob, alleging him of [Careless Driving](https://www.drinkdrivelaw.co.nz/dangerous-driving/#Careless%20Driving%20Explained). No charges are laid.

**Alice attempts to claim the costs of the doctor checkup and the jacket. Will she succeed?**

Jurisdiction: New Zealand, but also interested in any others.

Comment: How is she claiming them? Told Bob she wants the money? From her insurance? In a tribunal or court?

Comment: @Nij She told Bob she wants the money. He rejected. She is considering going to court.

Comment: She should be making the claim with his insurer, not Bob.

Comment: @RonBeyer Good point, but what if Bob has no insurance? This is legal in NZ.

Comment: Then Bob is acting as a self insurer, and she should sue him.

Comment: @RonBeyer The question is will she succeed and why. Was it Bob's negligence or just bad luck for both? Will she be entitled to the jacket only, or for the doctor visit as well, given that she paid one just in case and not in actual need?

Comment: @RonBeyer you don’t sue Bob’s insurer - you have no legal relationship with them. You sue Bob, if he has insurance he makes a claim and the insurer takes over as Bob’s agent.

Comment: Let's say Bob drove into my car, which was parked safely and legally. And he damaged the jacket. Is there a difference between my situation and Alice's? Did she accept the risk that Bob might make a mistake, while I didn't?

Comment: @DaleM I didn't suggest she should sue the insurer, you can put a claim in with somebody's insurance without suing them.

Comment: NZ has (I believe fairly unique) ACC - accident compensation -  laws - which I believe preclude Alice claiming her doctors bills from Bill, as the ACC pays the reasonable costs associated with medical care. (Which is funded by tax).  ACC does not, I believe cover the jacket.

Answer (score 3):

Barring any specific statute the relevant law is the tort of negligence. To succeed Alice must prove Bob:

1. had a duty to Alice,
2. breached that duty by failing to conform to the required standard of conduct (generally the standard of a reasonable person),
3. the negligent conduct was, in law, the cause of the harm to Alice, and
4. Alice was, in fact, harmed or damaged.

She will probably succeed on 1, 3 and 4 where she will struggle is with 2.

It seems that Bob did everything a reasonable person could do to avoid the accident. The only possible hope is that not knowing that bridges freeze first might be something a qualified NZ driver should know and that he breached his duty by not knowing if that is something the judge considers reasonable.

The traffic warning is irrelevant and untested (and untestable) hearsay and should be excluded from evidence.

Comment: If Bob drove into my correctly parked car instead, I would expect him to be liable and his insurance to pay my damages. And yet I think your answer is right as far as Alice is concerned. Can't figure out where the difference comes from. (I wouldn't be angry with Bob; I could have made the same mistake and then my insurance would pay Bob, but I would expect to be paid).

Comment: Driving into a car parked legally is an entirely different situation from driving on the open road and hitting poor conditions.

Comment: I'm obviously talking about driving on the open road, hitting poor conditions, and as a result driving into a legally parked car.

Comment: Notwithstanding with duty of care/negligence, does the fact that Alice _risked_ to be Bob's passenger make her any less entitled to costs? If not, would @gnasher729 not get anything (if his car was legally parked there and got damaged) from Bob for the same very reason as Alice?

Comment: Well for the parked car scenario, generally you report the damage to your insurance company who will then argue with the other insurance company over who is responsible for what. They usually don't tell you the final resolution, you just get a check.

Comment: @pboss3010 This question is curious about those "who is responsible for what" details, therefore assuming noone is insured.

Comment: Where I come from the principle is that "third party liability" pays if a third party is damaged, and the driver of the car is liable. "Acts of god" would be excluded. And your spouse, parents, children are not third parties (although insurance companies often pay voluntarily). It is highly recommended - by insurance salespeople - to have passenger insurance covering anyone inside your car.

Comment: And in case it's not obvious: If the driver is liable that's good for all people because the car's third party liability insurance will have to pay the damage.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is premised on principles of equity because (1) I am not knowledgeable of vehicle legislation, and (2) the rationale herein is portable across jurisdictions where legislative provisions or case law might be inconclusive.

> Alice attempts to claim the costs of the doctor checkup and the jacket. Will she succeed?

Unlikely. Bob should not be ordered to reimburse Alice.

At the outset, it is wrong for the police to impute to Bob careless driving. It is wrong because actually Bob took extra precautions in response to the challenging road conditions.

If the police alleged "*careless driving*" in Alice's presence, the police unduly prejudiced Bob. In that case, there is a chance that Alice would not have proceeded against Bob but for her awareness of the police's unfair depiction of Bob.

Bob's extra precautions disprove negligence. Given the absence of signs saying "*bridge freezes first*" and how unusual icy roads are in that region, an average driver from that region cannot be expected to know that bridges freeze first.

Since they suffered *only minor or no injuries*, Alice's motive for consulting a physician is questionable. Was that a result of the undue prejudice to Bob? did Alice have a preexisting medical condition? is she hypochondriac or suggestible? In such cases, Bob's driving can hardly be deemed a *proximate cause* of --or even contributory to-- Alice's needless medical expenses.

Alice's jacket is evidently expensive, or else she would have no incentive to require Bob to compensate her for the damaged jacket. Thus, a relevant question is *how* reasonable was it for Alice to wear a purportedly expensive (and perhaps ostentatious) jacket for what she knew was just a road trip in cold weather.

Neither Bob forced Alice to join the road trip, nor did he drive negligently. Therefore, he is not liable for what seemingly are Alice's self-inflicted losses.

Comment: Negligence is not an equitable doctrine, it’s a common law one.

Comment: @DaleM It is funny how you are nitpicking to justify downvoting the entire answer. Is "unfair prejudice to Bob" also common law? is reimbursement of Alice's self-inflicted losses also common law?

Comment: Whilst DaleM's answer is canonical, this one provides interesting angles to look at the case. Thank you.

Comment: You make a number of statements that are neither supported by the question nor reasonable in the circumstances, and several require an implication about what is or not lawful that are at best, ambiguous. Aming others: a jacket of exactly the kind one would wear on cold weather can cost several hundred dollars; the question says signs about bridge freezing are uncommon, not the icy weather itself; there is nothing to indicate Bob drove to the conditions, let alone took extra precautions above the necessary: the police have given a written warning and to call this undue prejudice is wrong.

Comment: @Nij The OP's feedback debunks your rant on this being "neither supported nor reasonable in the circumstances". Apply common sense, if you can: A lack of signs suggests that bridge freezing is unusual. I have spent several long winters where snow & icy roads are very common, and I have never needed a jacket that "can cost several hundred dollars"; only someone's personal taste can cost that much. I'm sorry you cannot discern between *conditional* and *unequivocal* statements of fact, but what I wrote ("**If** the police alleged 'careless driving' **in Alice's presence**") is a conditional one.

Comment: @IñakiViggers You don't know why Alice spent several hundred on a jacket.  She may have had good reasons.

Comment: @DavidThornley "*You don't know why Alice spent several hundred on a jacket. She may have had good reasons*". I agree, which is why I wrote that "*a relevant question is **how reasonable** was it for Alice*" to make certain decision(s) related to the jacket.